# Javascript Ad Conflicting With Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, css

Apart from repositioning is there anything that I can do to avoid the following that is described in the image

[image]

Here is a live link to the website [audio visual reviews](http://audiovisualreviews.net).

I have tried using javascript to hide the ads when the search list is displayed but it doesnt work.

Is this something that a css rule could fix.

Once again thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be better if you show some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

play with z-index.

be carefull, it works ONLY with ABSOLUTE and RELATIVE positions.

for the flash object, beware to have wmode=transparent.
wmode opaque is not working for z-index

Comment: thanks for your answer.. The ad code is in javascript so there is no embed object to add wmode=transparent. wmode

Comment: you can add the wmode with JS without problem, it's just an attribute to add. implement it depends on the library you are using

Answer (score 0):

You may set z-index to the popup window to be higher than the z-index that you will put on the div or whatever is holding your ads elements. I guess you are searching for:

```
#PopUpDivOrElement {
position:relative /*or position:absolute*/
z-index:20;
}
#addsDivOrElement {
position:relative /*or position:absolute*/
z-index:0;
}
```